# Many to many relationship in laravel pivot table

Tags: laravel-5

I am making a web application.In there i am making a quiz which has many quiz and one quiz has many questions.So There when using many to many relationship Do i have to build pivot table or will it create that automatically by laravel?

Comment: You would need a pivot table for the many-to-many relationship. Three tables might be needed in your situation: one for the quizzes, one for the questions, and one for joining those two together (perhaps "question_quiz" if you're using Laravel's naming convention).

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/30

Comment: okay.thank you all.I will try out this.